# Efficient way of working with Huge Arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, memory, multidimensional-array, julia

I have this very large arrays of experimental data that are gathered with a UI written in Python. The arrays are of the order of tens of Gigabytes in size, stored as unsigned integers and converted via known factors into floating point numbers. Typical sizes for this arrays are 64 by 64 by 10^5 entries. 
In the pythonic UI, everything runs very smoothly. We have visualizations in allmost real times, can plot many of the behaviours of each 1 dimensional subarray (in the long direction), load and close them. Then they are saved as hdf5 files.

When I try to process them numerically in Julia in a much better computer, everything becomes slugish. Super slow. Unresponsive. So I clearly must be doing something very wrong.

Actuall examples of the code would be the following functions:

```
function centerandreshapedata(xxs::Array, factor::Number)
    irrrelevant,largo=size(xxs)
    aux=Array{Int16}(undef, 64,64, largo);
    result=Array{Float16}(undef, 64,64, largo);
    for j=1:64,k=1:64
        aux[k,j,:]=xxs[j+(k-1)*64,:]
    end
    result=((aux.-2048).*factor);
    # factor is converting the floats to Float64
    result=convert.(Float16, result)
    return result
end


function DiscreteLaplacian(data)
    temp=copy(Datos)
    (mu,lu)=size(Datos)    
    izq=reshape(temp[1,:],(1,lu))
    der=reshape(temp[end,:],(1,lu))
    #Padding the data
    temp=vcat(izq, temp, der)
    temp=hcat(temp[:,1], temp, temp[:,end])
    largo,ancho=size(temp)
    aux=Array{Float32}(undef, 3,3)
    result=zeros(size(temp))

 for j=2:largo-1, k=2:ancho-1
        aux=temp[j-1:j+1,k-1:k+1]
        result[j,k]=sum(LaplacianKernel.*aux)
    end
    #DO  Crop the borders
    result=result[2:end-1,2:end-1]
    return result
end
```

Typical things that I need to do with these data are reshaping, applying finite difference operators, and other linear transformations, searching slice by slice for certain values, and things like that. The python UI seems to be much responsive than my Julia rutines. I am very puzzled by this.

Also plotting them with PyPlot.jl takes ages, but that may be another question.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using? It's hard to figure out what's wrong without concrete examples

Comment: From your description the most likely reason is that you are making copies of your data instead of using views when you subset them, but as indicated in the comment above it is hard to say without the actual code.

Comment: In numpy slices (`a[:, 2]` for example) are views. In Julia, the same notation produces a copy, as mentioned above. Read here for how to create views: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Views-(SubArrays-and-other-view-types)-1

Comment: This is a very broad question, specially without an [mvc example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can only do random suggestions and point you to [profiling tools](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/profile/) to help you find the bottlenecks of your program

Comment: Even without the concrete examples, I think all of you pointed in the right directions. I just added two examples of functions that I am runing over this very large arrays. One could use as an example data=randn(64,64,10^6) in my machine.